# With text labels for ticks in linear scale, zoom causes lables to extend beyond axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, graph-visualization

I created a d3 plot with linear scale x axis. I placed text label on xaxis using tickFormat().

When I zoom the plot, the tick values extend beyond xaxis. How do I make the ticks (with text labels) beyond xaxis (svg rect) disappear?

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickValues(idForXAxis)
  .tickFormat(function(d,i){ return valuesForXAxis[i] })
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wicedp/q1b2dsdt/4/

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not `tickFormat`. You can easily find the culprit: remove `tickValues` and the ticks will stay within the range.

The best idea is simply letting D3 generates the ticks. But, if you want to show all the values in the `valuesForXAxis` array in the original view and still have a zoom behaviour formatting the ticks, there is a workaround. Set the tick number as the number of values inside `valuesForXAxis` array:

```
xAxis.ticks(idForXAxis.length)
```

And then, inside your `zoomed` function:

```
xAxis.ticks(idForXAxis.length/d3.event.scale);
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pfrdvLtx/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I used your suggestion and now the values stay within range. But, its always showing values of array - "valuesForXAxis" from index 0 to "idForXAxis.length/d3.event.scale". When I add a line plot and zoom it, the plot and xaxis are out of sync.

Comment: Here is the fiddle with that change. https://jsfiddle.net/wicedp/c6m2wkms/
It probably just needs a offset for the start index and end index of "valuesForXAxis" array.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by adding this piece of code -

```
var clipX = svg.append("clipPath")
  .attr('id', 'clip-x-axis')
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', -10)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', margin.bottom);

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip-x-axis)')
.attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
.call(xAxis)
.selectAll(".tick text")
  .call(wrap, 0);
```

This way I think xaxis was getting correctly translated and clipped. Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/wicedp/q1b2dsdt/12/